# Is there any python module to divide a number N into 3 parts such that sum of that parts equal to N? or how to do that?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

- I tried gcd But didn't work.
- n = 18 # given number n
- x = 3 # 3 parts or x number of part

## OUTPUT ->

## (1,9,8),(2,8,8),(3,6,9)......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look to the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/itertools.html) library. Use `product` to get a powerset-like output and filter by a condition.

```
import itertools as it

n = 4
partitions = 3

combs = [comb for comb in it.product(range(n), repeat=partitions) if sum(comb) == n]
print(*combs, sep='\n')
```

Remark: if `0` is not desired change the "list" with `range(1, n+1)`

Answer (score -1):

i don't really understand what your asking but this could work:

```
n = input("pick a number for n: ")
print(str(n), "divide by 3 is", str(n/3))
```

answer:

```
pick a number for n: 6
6 divide by 3 is 2
```

also there is a module called [math](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html)

Comment: (1, 9, 8) -> 1 + 9 + 8 = 18 and so on

Comment: did you want all possible lists printed for n?